# MYSQL cursors where current of

Tags: mysql, cursor

```
*DELIMITER //
create procedure test(OUT l_out INT)
begin
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
declare l_sno INT default 0;
declare a INT default 0;
declare b INT default 0;
declare cur_1 cursor for select sno,interest from temp t  where x_coord between 55 and 60 for update of interest;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
open cur_1; 
read_loop: LOOP
fetch cur_1 into a,b;
if done then
    Leave read_loop;
end if;
set l_sno=l_sno+1;
update temp set interest =1 where CURRENT OF cur_1;
END LOOP;
close cur_1;
set l_out=l_sno;
end //
;*
```

Error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'of interest; DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; open cur_1;' at line 7
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OF cur_1; END LOOP; close cur_1; set l_out=l_sno; end' at line 16

Comment: I think those error messages pretty much explain it all, don't they?  `OF INTEREST` and `CURRENT OF` aren't valid MySQL syntax... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to update based on current cursor position

Comment: Then delete `OF INTEREST` and replace `CURRENT OF cur_1` with whatever criteria specify the record(s) you wish to update.

Comment: but that will slow down the speed as it will scan the database fully

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like you are coming from a different kind of SQL, like DB2 -- there those work.

Quote from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursor-restrictions.html

> Cursors are read only; you cannot use a cursor to update rows.
>
> UPDATE WHERE CURRENT OF and DELETE WHERE CURRENT OF are not implemented, because updatable cursors are not supported.

So I guess you can't do it that way and you'll have to specify a mysql-like where clause.